# Easier way to type multiple lines on a diagonal path in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography

I'm trying to make my paragraph at an angle like this:
[image]

Right now the only way i've been able to do this was through blending two lines and then using type on a path + threading text across the lines like so:

[image]

Is there any easier way to achieve the same effect? I tried just rotating the whole paragraph but i can't get a straight left edge that way. Please help.

Answer (score 12):

- Make a text box with the content
- Rotate it -15º
- Deselect
- Use the **Direct Selection Tool** and click the text box edge holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> to select just the frame shape
- Shear it -15º

[image]